# Input HTML5 in IE9

Tags: css, html, input, internet-explorer-9

I hope you could help me with maybe simple problem with HTML5 in IE9
In my code I have few things:

```
<input type="text" id="fn" name="fn" placeholder="Street" autofocus/>
---------------------------------------------------------------------
/* INPUT TEXT */
input[type="text"]
{
    border:2px solid #dadada;
    border-radius:7px;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:5px; 
}

input[type="text"]:focus
{ 
    outline:none;
    border-color:#9ecaed;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

In Opera, Chrome and Firefox all is good, but in IE9 nothing...
I tried to include in head before linking CSS file this lines:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?
This CSS does not work in IE9 (in IE9 are normal input), in Opera, Chrome, Firefox are nice radius and colors inputs.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, and what is your question?

Comment: `text` is not one of these new HTML5 types of input, it's been there forever. And why I are you including `html5shiv` in IE9 when it's of no use in this version of IE? It's useful in IE8, 7 and 6 developed when HTML5 didn't exist yet, not in IE9, 10 and in a near future IE11 and so on.

Comment: And what's the problem? placeholder?

Comment: I have problem that it does not work in IE9, it is working in Opera, Chrome, Firefox, but not in IE9...

Comment: @jaajja "Doesn't work" isn't really helpful. What do you expect to see that you don't?

Comment: Also, the point of `html5shiv` isn't to make HTML5 features work on legacy IE. It's to fix around a bug in IE where it will simply not include unrecognized elements (such as `<article>`) in the DOM at all, whereas other browsers will. All it does is make the new elements appear as plain `<div>`s, nothing else.

Comment: In Firefox i can see radius, color and border, In IE i can see only normal text input.

Comment: On a side note: The placeholder attribute isn't supported in IE9 and earlier. If default text in IE9 is a requirement, you'll need to add some JavaScript. Other than that, it seems to work fine for me in IE9 (using IE10 in IE9 mode, with no shiv, which doesn't seem needed).

Answer (score 4):

The only issue I see different between IE9 and Opera/Chrome/Firefox is that it doesn't support the `placeholder` HTML5 attribute. You can view this jsFiddle to verify the broken behavior in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/dndrS/ and also reference [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder) to see the support of input placeholder attribute.

IE10 does support the placeholder attribute, so you can either upgrade or if you'd like to support IE9 then you can use the following polyfill https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder by Mathias Bynens. Here is a jsFiddle using the polyfill http://jsfiddle.net/nyTMw/ that works in IE9

A handy website to look for other polyfills is http://html5please.com/